# How to debug android callbacks?

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to use the Eclipse debugger to debug my Android application, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have a callback in my `MasterActivity.java` file for `onOptionsItemSelected`, and I set a breakpoint in this method at a point that I know is being hit.  I then right click my application, and go to `Debug As -> Android Application`.  When I click the button in the ActionBar that triggers this callback and should start the debugging process, my program just continues like my breakpoint is not there.  I must be missing something basic here, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simon's suggestion to add a Log message is a good start to ensure that the callback is being called, unless there is already some other evidence unique to the callback that it is being triggered.  We can only guess as you haven't included any code, and nothing wastes time like a programmer assuming they are correct, myself included ;-)

However, try adding a call to [waitForDebugger()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29) just prior to the line with the breakpoint active.

Comment: `nothing wastes time like a programmer assuming they are correct` An excellent quote, and totally might be true in this case (+1).

Comment: Thanks for this! Hard to believe that 5 years later debugging in Android one still stumbles across this issue. I am embarrassed to say how much time was wasted trying to figure out why a callback wasn't firing, when in fact it was. For me, this happens on IntelliJ so this isn't an eclipse thing. It must be an Android SDK thing.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check if an item, in this case a menu item I guess, is to use the method Log.d(String tag, String message). So in your onOptionsItemSelected event handler, you can add e.g Log.d("Debug", "Options item is selected"). It isn't necessary to use Debug As, Run As will work too. The log message will be displayed in blue in the LogCat in Eclipse.

Comment: I know how to print to the log, but I want to do debugging by stepping.

Comment: Why can't you use the log for debugging?

Comment: Because I prefer stepping...?  It gives me more control over the debugging process and takes less time.  If it's possible I want to know how.

Comment: What do you mean with stepping?

Comment: I prefer to use a debugger that lets me step through each line of code, stopping at each point and displaying values for all variables, letting me inspect them, etc etc.  Debugging with print statements is time consuming.

Comment: That's true, I understand you. Unfortunatelly I don't know such a debugger so I can't help you with that