# IntelliJ/Android Studio debugging: Breakpoint in callback does not get called

Tags: debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using Retrofit in my Application, like this:

```
    beforeFubar();
    MyRetrofitApi.getFoo(new Callback<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Foo arg0, Response arg1) {
        successFubar();

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
        failureFubar(); 
        }
    });
```

I put my breakpoints at

- `beforeFubar()`,
- `successFubar()`
- `failureFubar()`

Breakpoint at `beforeFubar()` gets called correctly and executions stops

BUT

Breakpoints at `successFubar()` and `failureFubar()` do not get called (but they are executed)

Please, what am I missing here?

---

**EDIT**

it seems that the issue gets solved if I set Suspend All when I set the breakpoint.

Please what is your experience? Does this solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: what is the version of you android studio?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Hi mechanic, it's 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue was reported in the past and seems to get fixed by adding a call to [waitForDebugger()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29) just prior to the line with the breakpoint active.

Source : [How to debug android callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885190/how-to-debug-android-callbacks)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mechanic. This will litter the code with a lot of extra lines :-((( Do you have an idea why this started happening all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

Because of your ADB (Android Debug Bridge) configuration and settings this problem may happen.

Manipulate following solutions according to your conditions:

- If you debug your app on a test device through WiFi switch to USB
- If you  debug on an AVD, try to Restart AS and then reestablish again
- Restart adb server with the following commands and also your PC:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

just update   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'  to the latest version
if it dosent work , you must upgrade your android studio to the latest version